# MongoDB Update Query Nested Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-update

I have a data structure for a typical movie theatre:

```
{ 
      "_id": ObjectId("5bdadf3k28ds2sdfdasbf321"),
      "seats": [
        [
          {
            "status": "VACANT",
            "code": "1A"
          },
          {
            "status": "VACANT",
            "code": "1B"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "status": "VACANT",
            "code": "2A"
          },
          {
            "status": "VOID",
            "code": "2B"
          }
        ]
      ]
}
```

How do I create an update mongoDB command to update seat with codes "1A" and "2A" to "TAKEN" if and only if their status is "VACANT" ?

I have browsed aroound but i haven't quite gotten hold of it..

Can I do something like following?

```
db.coll.update({}, {$set: {“seats.$[i].$[j].status”: "TAKEN"}}, {arrayFilters: [{“j.code”: "1A"}, {“j.code”: "2A"}]})
```

Comment: use ```db.coll.update({}, { $set: { "seats.$[].$[j].status": "TAKEN"} }, { arrayFilters: [{ "j.code": {$in:["1A", "2A"]}}] })```

Comment: If you want multiple conditions for j, use ```db.coll.update({}, { $set: { "seats.$[].$[j].status": "TAKEN"} }, { arrayFilters: [{ $and : [ {"j.code": {$in:["1A", "2A"]}}, {"j.status":"VACANT"}]}] })```

Comment: but it seems thatt if there is no seat with code 1A status VACANT, query still returns as succesful...I need it to return an error if it cannot find what i was looking to update

Comment: It will always return as successful, You need to use ```nModified``` from writeResult to check if any record was modified or not. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#writeresults-update